# Customize XFCE on Xubuntu custom Live CD

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce, live-cd, customization

I followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization and my custom iso worked, it booted and I have apps I installed and a few scripts I added. I'd like now to customize the GUI: keyboard layout, panel , menu screensaver, etc.

I was able to make the changes I want from normal live, using Panel Preferences and MenuLibre, but I can't find out how to do it on customizing the live CD. Am I able to run them while customizing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd).  Specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679)

Comment: I had seen that. It uses ubuntu-builder which isn't being maintained anymore and customizes Gnome :/

Comment: The answer that I linked does not use ubuntu builder or any discontinued software.  It still works.